# How to listen for a command with multiple arguments?

Tags: java, command, arguments, chat

I've created a chat in java with a GUI and a textField to send Messages. I can also type for commands (like "§example") there.
But In the chat I want to create a "§kick [user]" command. How can I get the argument [user] in the

```
public void runCommand() {
    if(textField.getText().equals("§kick")) {
        appendTextMessages("kicked " + user);
        textField.setText(null);
        textField.requestFocus();
    }
}
```

Hope you understand the question!
Thanks in advance

Comment: Didn't understand your question.

Comment: maybe if your text startsWith(user), then you can just split the string and try to parse the user name, is that the question?

Comment: If I type "§kick otto" it should do something with otto but if I type "§kick carl" it takes carl. My question is how can I read the name after the "§kick"

Comment: @Leo yes that is my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
String text = textField.getText();
if(text.starstWith("§kick ")) {
    String user = text.substring("§kick ".length());
    // kick user
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Glad it helped! Please accept it if it answered your question :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, typically I click a button to submit what I've typed into whatever text field to whatever website/web-app I'm submitting to... So, when I click that button, you check the contents of that text field to get what I've inputted and process it in essentially the same way you learned to do so with a `Scanner` in introductory Java,